# How to implement .NET Core tutorial to .NET Framework?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a project in ASP.NET Framework 4.7.2 which uses Azure AD and MSAL to access data from server API within my company. However all the Microsoft tutorials are for .NET Core, and there no much examples for .NET framework. So I am wondering how one can implement the .NET Core tutorial to .NET framework.

For example, in the following Microsoft tutorial, a sample Program.cs code is given. However there is no Program.cs in .NET framework.
[text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-tutorial-03-sign-in-users?tabs=visual-studio)
How I can use the example code in my .NET framework project?

Comment: It's not just runtime framework difference. All the NuGet packages are different. There is no straightforward way to do it. Or, mostly, no way at all.

Answer (score 0):

As Vlad said different .net runtime use the different AAD and MSAL packages. The .net framework is still in support. So it contains its own AAD nad MSAL packages.

According your description , I  suggest you could follow the Microsoft tutorials to download or check the samples which use the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) for .NET to acquire an access token for Microsoft Graph. You could modify using the access token to get the user information and use it to call the Web API from your company which protected by the AAD.

More details ,you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-aspnet-daemon-web-app#scenario).